# Only show column if it changed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this table:

```
some_id | page_id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
   1    |   1     |    1    |    1    |    1    |    1    | 
   1    |   2     |    1    |    0    |    1    |    1    | 
   1    |   3     |    1    |    0    |    1    |    1    | 
   2    |   2     |    1    |    0    |    0    |    1    | 
   2    |   3     |    1    |    0    |    1    |    0    |
   3    |   6     |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |
```

In this table, **some_id** and **page_id** are foreign keys.

Now I show this (in a table) in php like so:

```
some_id | page_id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
   some1|   page1 |    yes  |    yes  |    yes  |    yes  | 
   some1|   page2 |    yes  |    no   |    yes  |    yes  | 
   some1|   page3 |    yes  |    no   |    yes  |    yes  | 
   some2|   page2 |    yes  |    no   |    no   |    yes  | 
   some2|   page3 |    yes  |    no   |    yes  |    no   |
   some3|   page6 |    no   |    no   |    no   |    no   |
```

but I want it like this:

```
some_id | page_id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
   some1|   page1 |    yes  |    yes  |    yes  |    yes  | 
        |   page2 |    yes  |    no   |    yes  |    yes  | 
        |   page3 |    yes  |    no   |    yes  |    yes  | 
   some2|   page2 |    yes  |    no   |    no   |    yes  | 
        |   page3 |    yes  |    no   |    yes  |    no   |
   some3|   page6 |    no   |    no   |    no   |    no   |
```

So basically everytime there's a new **some_id** only then it should show the result. If there isn't it should be an empty `td`. I have no idea how to do this.

This is the array with the results of the query:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#351 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(2)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#352 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(2)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(6)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#353 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(2)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(7)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#354 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [4]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#355 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(2)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [5]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#356 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(3)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [6]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#357 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [7]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#358 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(5)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [8]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#359 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(6)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
  [9]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#360 (6) {
    ["some_id"]=&gt;
    int(4)
    ["page_id"]=&gt;
    int(7)
    ["column1"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column2"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column3"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["column4"]=&gt;
    int(1)
  }
}
```

And this is how I show it:

```
@foreach ($array as $something)
<tr>
<td>{{$something->some_id}}</td>
<td>{{$something->page_id}}</td>
<td>{{$something->column1}}</td>
<td>{{$something->column2}}</td>
<td>{{$something->column3}}</td>
<td>{{$something->column4}}</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

How can I get it as the desired result I described and showed above? With every **some_id** only shown once and in the row where it comes up first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use PHP, you don't need SQL to do that.

before your loop initialize a variable to keep track of the value of some_id.

I'm not familiar with the notation you are using so I set this up to work the way I would do it.

```
<?php
    $currId = '';
    @foreach ($array as $something) {
?>
      <tr>
        <?php if ($something->some_id != $currId) {
          $currId = $something->some_id;
        ?>

          <td><?php echo $something->some_id; ?></td>

        <?php } else { ?>

          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <?php } ?>

        <td><?php echo $something->page_id]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $something->column1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $something->column2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $something->column3; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $something->column4; ?></td>

      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I was thinking about this but I want to show the name that belongs to the id. like instead of the id, I'd have the primary key from another table linked to that some_id. If I would use this then I'd have to loop through all the id's and have a query for all the id's even the duplicates? Which is a lot of unnecessary queries?

Comment: nevermind. With some changes in your code, it can work in Laravel.

Comment: You could probably add to your SQL query to get the name instead of the ID returned with the results.  That would probably be the best way. If you want help with your query, create a new question and post a link to it here if you can.

Comment: No I got it. I know how to do that, but that's not the solution I want. Anyway your part helped me so I accept it.

Comment: OK, well I'm here to help.  Not really about the rep.  So if you have any other questions just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your template clean, you can do it like this:

```
$previous = '';

$callback = function(&$item, $key, &$previous) {
    if ($item->some_id == $previous) {
        $item->some_id = '&nbsp;';
    } else {
        $previous = $item->some_id;
    }
};

array_walk($array, $callback, $previous);
```